# Global variable referenced before assignment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I'm brand new to Python and I'm trying to create a very simple code where every time the user presses enter, they earn five points, followed by the line printing how many points they currently have. The code looks like this:

```
pointsEarned = 0
alien_0 = {"points":5}
new_points = alien_0["points"]
def kill():
    input("Press enter to kill an alien!")
    pointsEarned = pointsEarned + 5
    killed()
def killed():
    print("You just earned " + str(new_points) + " points!")
    print("Current points: " + str(pointsEarned))
    kill()
kill()
```

However, when I run this code, it gives me this error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pointsEarned' referenced before assignment
```

I don't understand this, as I defined pointsEarned outside of either function beforehand. How do I fix this?

Comment: Declare variable explicitly as `global`. If a variable is on the left side of an assignment anywhere in a function it is seen as local if not declared otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
pointsEarned = 0
alien_0 = {"points":5}
new_points = alien_0["points"]
def kill():
    global pointsEarned 
    input("Press enter to kill an alien!") 
    pointsEarned += 5
    killed()
def killed():
    print("You just earned " + str(new_points) + " points!")
    print("Current points: " + str(pointsEarned))
    kill()
kill()
```